# How to adjust sensitivity of Windows 10 volume control touchpad three-finger gestures

Tags: windows-10, audio, touchpad, gestures, mouse-gestures

Windows 10 has a *Touchpad* setting to allow *Three-finger gestures* to *Change audio and volume*.

I find three-finger-dragging up and down changes the volume too quickly, making it easy to accidentally make it too loud or soft.

How can I change only the sensitivity of this control, and not the sensitivity of the touchpad for other uses, e.g. normal mouse movements?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked the touchpad software in control panel?

Comment: Yes, the "Change the cursor speed" slider changes both the volume change rate, and mouse movement rate. I'd like only the former changed, and can't find anything relevant.